# PHP ordered list from latest post

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 divisions in my table, first is the "ID", second is the "TOPIC", then lastly is the "DATE POSTED". I have this prob, I can't make the new topic be on top. it just goes on the last of the list. Now, how can I make the latest topic that I posted be on top of my lists?

my codes:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM PythoN_Blog")or die(mysql_error());
echo "<table border='0' width='700'>"; 
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td  align='center' style='padding-left:30;'>".$result['id']."</td>";
    echo "<td  align='center' style='padding-left:10;'><a href='#'>".$result['topic']."</a></td>";
    echo "<td  align='center'>".$result['date']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";   
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM PythoN_Blog order by DATE_POSTED DESC

Comment: Aditionally, I cannot find any actual dup in the site, but any basic MySQL tutorial will answer this so I flag it as not constructive.

Comment: Thanks Soaica Mircea..

Answer (score 6):

Change your query to this

```
"SELECT * FROM PythoN_Blog order by DATE_POSTED DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

if your DATE_POSTED column is NOT datetime format (e.g. varchar) then you have to convert it:

```
"SELECT * FROM PythoN_Blog ORDER BY CONVERT(DateTime, DATE_POSTED,103)  DESC"
```

if your DATE_POSTED column is datetime format then:

```
"SELECT * FROM PythoN_Blog ORDER BY 'DATE_POSTED' DESC";
```